# The application icon remains the same

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a WPF application (.net core 3.1) and then towards the end I wanted to change the icon, as usual I opened the properties>application and loaded my icon. But it doesn't change anything... remains the same default icon.
The size of my icon is 256x256 and obviously has an .ico format. I tried to delete the folder where the executable is located and to build again, I also tried to run the application without debugging mode, but nothing. I noticed, however, that the main window when you change the Icon attribute updates the window icon. But nothing to do for the .exe file.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

P.S. I don't think it's the icon the problem because I tried to load another icon that I used in the past with another WPF application

Comment: The .ico format allows for the storage of multiple icon formats in the same file. Consider adding smaller format icons; Windows may have trouble scaling down your icon. Also note that the Windows shell caches icons, your changes may take a while before they seem to "catch"

Comment: @Flydog57 I compiled the project in release mode and there's the new icon. So the problem was the cache. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, making changes to icons is always a pain.  You make the change and you don't see it until you reboot your box.  I really wish that I knew how to invalidate that cache.

Comment: Initially I tried to clear the cache from the cmd, but despite the administrator privileges I did not have access to do this

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution in Solution Explorer and click on "Rebuild Solution" or "Clean Solution" followed by "Build Solution".

Comment: I had already tried to do this, but it didn't work. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: If that didn't help, use a different file name. For example, if the file name was app.ico, try using app1.ico and so on.